# HTML table not working

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to program a website when the table function stopped working. The rest of the page loads but there is no table.

```css
body {} .backgroundimage {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.button1 {
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
}
.button2 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}
.menu {
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.titlebanner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-width: 25%;
}
.titlesection {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 20%;
  top: -100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Adina White Photography
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets\CodeFiles\CssFile.css" />
  <link rel=" icon" href="Assets\Pictures\TabIcon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="titlesection">
    <img class="titlebanner" src="Assets\Pictures\BannerIcon.png" alt="Uh-Oh,     This image was too dank to load." />
  </div>
  <table style="width:100%; z-index:1;">
    <tr>
      <!--the error is here somewhere-->
      <th>content</th>
      <th>content</th>
      <th>content</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="top:-150px;height:100%;z-index:1;background-color:transparent;position:relative;text-align:left;">
    <img class="backgroundimage" src="Assets\Pictures\winterscene.jpg" alt="Uh-Oh, This image was too dank to load." />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need the Z-indexs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is there, but you cannot see it because it is invisible since there are no borders or rows, only headers. Once you add that, you can see it, as demonstrated here:

```
<table style="width:100%; z-index:1;" border=1> 
<tr>
 <th>content</th> <th>content</th>  <th>content</th> 
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td> 
 </tr> 
</table>
```